# Google Android OS on x86?

Tags: installation, android, x86

How can I install Google's Android OS on an x86 platform?

Are there any prerequisites for doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hilariously, there actually is a project for [porting Android to the x86](http://www.android-x86.org/), currently on v1.6r2.

- download an ISO
- follow instructions for installing to VM's.  I used VMWare 6.5 but I think there were Virtualbox instructions too.
- choose install to HD.  I setup and formatted a 7GB ext3 partition, type 83, no swap.
- install was really quick, boot was much faster than my Motorola A-855 (course this a P4 Xeon)

UI behaves a lot like the droid, browser responds to kinetic scrolling.  I haven't tried turning my CPU sideways to see if it auto flips the screen though...

They claim it even supports NTFS partitions and dual booting.

[image]

Comment: This comment was posted from an x86 Android VM.  Had to reboot once, though as it just locked up.

Comment: does your CPU have the built-in accelerometer?  awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure that this is not really all that possible at the moment.  It was written for a different chipset, ARM processors, not x86, so you would need the source and to compile it. Any parts of the kernel that are in assembly, if there are any, would have to be rewritten.

The SDK does come with a good emulator.  Maybe that is what you mean when you mention install it.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a pre-existing port of Android to x86, called Remix OS. http://www.jide.com/remixos

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if included link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer.